# Explicitly granting permissions to update the sequence for a serial column necessary?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, sequence

Recently I did create a table as a superuser including a serial id column, e.g.,

```
create table my_table
(
    id serial primary key,
    data integer
);
```

As I wanted my non-superuser user to have write access to that table, I granted it permissions:

```
grant select, update, insert, delete on table my_table to writer;
```

At a random point in time after doing so, the insertions made by that user started to fail because the user lacked permission to modify the sequence `my_table_id_seq` associated to the serial column. Unfortunately I can't reproduce that on my current database.

I worked around this by giving the user the required permission, like this:

```
grant all on table my_table_id_seq to writer;
```

Can someone help me understand

- why, at some point, the previously sufficient permissions might start to fail?
- what is the proper way to grant write permission for a table with a serial column?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You most probably need:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE my_table_id_seq TO writer;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html)

> USAGE
> ...
> For sequences, this privilege allows the use of the `currval` and `nextval` functions.

`nextval()` is the reason you need the `USAGE` privilege on the sequence for a table with `serial` column.

- [Safely rename tables using serial primary key columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14651788/939860)

Since a sequence is a special kind of table (and for historical reasons) `GRANT ... ON TABLE` works on sequences, too. But you do *not* normally need that at all.

Since **Postgres 10**, we can use **`IDENTITY`** columns instead of `serial`. Those use bound sequences without separate permissions internally. See:

- [What are Identity Columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158988/what-are-identity-columns)
- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860)

Comment: Don't we need UPDATE ON  SEQUENCE for this?

Comment: @anshupitlia: Nope. As explained above.

Answer (score -1):

```
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO username;
```

For all sequences.

Comment: That isn't at all what the question is about.

Comment: This answer is good information, although not for the question asked.