# What are Identity Columns?

Tags: postgresql, identity, postgresql-10

I was reviewing the [commit-fest scheduled for 7/01](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/12/767/) for PostgreSQL and I saw that Pg is likely going to get "identity columns" sometime soon.

I found some mention in [information_schema.columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html) but nothing much

```
is_identity         yes_or_no         Applies to a feature not available in PostgreSQL
identity_generation character_data    Applies to a feature not available in PostgreSQL
identity_start      character_data    Applies to a feature not available in PostgreSQL
identity_increment  character_data    Applies to a feature not available in PostgreSQL
identity_maximum    character_data    Applies to a feature not available in PostgreSQL
identity_minimum    character_data    Applies to a feature not available in PostgreSQL
identity_cycle      yes_or_no         Applies to a feature not available in PostgreSQL
```

[The Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_column) doesn't say much either

> An identity column differs from a primary key in that its values are managed by the server and usually cannot be modified. In many cases an identity column is used as a primary key; however, this is not always the case.

But, I don't see anything else on them. How do identity columns work? Do they provide any new functionality or is this just a standard method to create sequences? Any breakdown of the new feature and how it works?

Comment: See excellent post [*PostgreSQL 10 identity columns explained*](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/#comment-248607) by Peter Eisentraut. He explains some weird issues that plague `SERIAL` but not the new `GENERATED … AS IDENTITY` feature.

Comment: See my [own Answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44982117/642706) discussing the syntax and behaviors of `GENERATED … AS IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## How they're actually implemented in PG 10

You can see how they're actually implemented now using the [test suite's expected output.](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/3217327053638085d24dd4d276e7c1f7ac2c4c6b/src/test/regress/expected/identity.out)

Some keys to take away from this.

- You can specify where to start and how many to skip with a clause on table creation or through `ALTER TABLE`, `START 7 INCREMENT BY 5`
- Inserting into a table with an identity column can now `OVERRIDING USER VALUE` for the identity column which forces a replacement of the conflicting row:

  ```
  INSERT INTO t OVERRIDING USER VALUE VALUES (10, 'xyz');

  -- this isn't currently allowed.
  CREATE TABLE t ( a serial PRIMARY KEY, b text );
  INSERT INTO t (a,b) VALUES (1,'foo');
  INSERT INTO t (a,b) VALUES (1,'bar');
  ```
- You can specify `GENERATED ALWAYS` to ensure generation then you need only have `OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE` to ignore that or you'll get an error when you `INSERT` a row that specifies a value for an identity column.

  ```
  ERROR:  cannot insert into column "a"
  DETAIL:  Column "a" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS.
  HINT:  Use OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE to override.
  ```
- Identity columns must be `NOT NULL`
- Permissions propagate from the table, no more underlying sequences.
- Identity can be reset entirely at a different point with `RESTART`

You can read more about these in the PostgreSQL 10 docs for

- [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-altertable.html)

  ```
  ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name ADD GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY [ ( sequence_options ) ]
  ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name DROP IDENTITY [ IF EXISTS ]
  ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name { SET GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } | SET sequence_option | RESTART [ [ WITH ] restart ] } [...]
  ```
- [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-createtable.html)

  ```
  GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY [ ( sequence_options ) ]
  ```
- [`CREATE SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) providing the `sequence_option` mentioned above

Answer (score 30):

This is to implement the feature found in the standard. (copied from a draft, date: 2011-12-21):

> 4.15.11 **Identity columns**
>
> The columns of a base table BT can optionally include not more than one **identity column**. The declared type
>   of an identity column is either an exact numeric type with scale 0 (zero), `INTEGER` for example, or a distinct
>   type whose source type is an exact numeric type with scale 0 (zero). **An identity column has a start value, an
>   increment, a maximum value, a minimum value, and a cycle option.** 
>   ...
>   ...  The definition of an identity column
>   may specify `GENERATED ALWAYS` or `GENERATED BY DEFAULT`.

It is a **property of a column** which basically says that the values for the column will be provided by the DBMS and not by the user and in some specific manner and restrictions (increasing, decreasing, having max/min values, cycling if the max/min value is reached).

**Sequence generators** (usually called just "sequences") are a related SQL standard feature: it's a mechanism that provides such values - and can be used for identity columns.

Note the subtle difference: a `SEQUENCE` is an object that can be used to provide values for one or more identity columns or even at will.

---

The various DBMS have so far implemented similar features in different ways and syntax (MySQL: `AUTO_INCREMENT`, SQL Server: `IDENTITY (seed, increment)`, PostgreSQL: `serial` using `SEQUENCE`, Oracle: using triggers, etc) and only recently added sequence generators (SQL Server in version 2012 and Oracle in 12c).

Up to now Postgres has implemented sequence generators (which can be used to provide values for column, either with the special macros `serial` and `bigserial` or with `nextval()` function) but has not yet implemented the syntax for identity columns, as it is in the standard.

Defining identity columns (and the slight difference from `serial` columns) and various syntax (eg. `GENERATED ALWAYS`, `NEXT VALUE FOR`, etc) from the SQL standard is what this feature is about. Some changes / improvements may need to be done on the implementation of sequences as well, as identity columns will be using sequences.

If you follow the link [identitity columns](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/6adbacbf-73bc-dd1a-2033-63409180fd18@2ndquadrant.com#6adbacbf-73bc-dd1a-2033-63409180fd18@2ndquadrant.com) (from the page you saw), you'll find:

> **identity columns**
>
> From:     Peter Eisentraut 
>   To:   pgsql-hackers 
>   Subject:  identity columns
>   Date:     2016-08-31 04:00:42
>   Message-ID:  6adbacbf-73bc-dd1a-2033-63409180fd18@2ndquadrant.com
>
> ---
>
> Here is another attempt to implement identity columns.  This is a
>   standard-conforming variant of PostgreSQL's serial columns.  It also
>   fixes a few usability issues that serial columns have:
>
> - need to set permissions on sequence in addition to table (*)
> - `CREATE TABLE` / `LIKE` copies default but refers to same sequence
> - cannot add/drop serialness with `ALTER TABLE`
> - dropping default does not drop sequence
> - slight weirdnesses because serial is some kind of special macro
>
> (*) Not actually implemented yet, because I wanted to make use of the
>   `NEXT VALUE FOR` stuff I had previously posted, but I have more work to
>   do there.
>
> ...

**Update 2017, September:** seems like the feature will be in Postgres 10, which is to be released in a few days/weeks:  [What's New In Postgres 10: Identity Columns](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/6adbacbf-73bc-dd1a-2033-63409180fd18@2ndquadrant.com#6adbacbf-73bc-dd1a-2033-63409180fd18@2ndquadrant.com)

---

Oracle have also implemented identity columns and sequences, in version 12c. The syntax is according to the standard, as far as I checked:
[Identity Columns in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1)

> The 12c database introduces the ability define an identity clause against a table column defined using a numeric type. The syntax is show below.
>
> ```
> GENERATED
> [ ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT [ ON NULL ] ]
> AS IDENTITY [ ( identity_options ) ]
> ```

Comment: Oh, that's actually kind of cool `GENERATED ALWAYS` would ignore the `INSERT` row's value for the specified column. That would be cool to permit on any column with a DEFAULT.

Comment: What happens to a `GENERATED ALWAYS` identity column when you want to `restore` data from a backup or move it from one DB to another?

Comment: @joanolo the implementation of the feature is currently in progress. If I find out, I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

## SQL 2003 Summary

For a good review of the spec on this here is a column entitled, [*SQL:2003 Has Been Published*](https://sigmodrecord.org/publications/sigmodRecord/0403/E.JimAndrew-standard.pdf) from [SIGMOD](https://sigmodrecord.org/)

> **Identity Columns**
>   While sequence generators put SQL in charge of
>   generating unique values, users are still burdened
>   with tasks such as creating a sequence generator and
>   invoking the NEXT VALUE FOR function at
>   appropriate times. SQL:2003 provides another new
>   feature, identity columns, that provides a more
>   convenient mechanism by making it unnecessary for
>   users to perform these additional tasks.
>   Identity columns are columns designated with the
>   special keyword IDENTITY, as shown below:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE PARTS (
> PARTNUM INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS
> AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1
> INCREMENT BY 1
> MINVALUE 1
> MAXVALUE 10000
> NO CYCLE),
> DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (100),
> QUANTITY INTEGER )
> ```
>
> As can be seen from the above example, identity
>   columns share the same attributes as sequence
>   generators. This is because a sequence generator that
>   inherits the identity column attributes gets associated
>   conceptually with each identity column. Note that at
>   most one column in a table can be designated as an
>   identity column.
>   Users do not need to specify a value for an
>   identity column whenever a new row is inserted into
>   a table containing that identity column. The value for
>   such a column is generated automatically by invoking
>   the NEXT VALUE FOR function implicitly under the
>   covers. For example, the following INSERT
>   statement:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO PARTS
> (DESCRIPTION, QUANTITY)
> VALUES ('WIDGET', 30)
> ```
>
> adds a new part named WIDGET to the PARTS
>   table. The value for the PARTNUM column is
>   generated automatically, following the same rules
>   that are used for generating values of sequence
>   generators. That is, the value of PARTNUM column
>   for the first row would be the START WITH value
>   specified for that column, and the values for
>   subsequent rows would follow the formula we
>   described previously for sequence generators.
>   What we said above is true if the user had
>   specified GENERATED ALWAYS for the identity
>   column, which is the case for PARTNUM column in
>   our example. SQL:2003 provides another option,
>   GENERATED BY DEFAULT. If the user chooses
>   this option, automatic generation takes place only
>   when values are not provided in the VALUES clause.
>   This feature is very useful for making copies of tables
>   with identity columns.