# Is it safe to rely on auto increments even after restoring data?

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

I plan of using auto increments as a primary key on one of my table.

I need to store data related to each row in an other storage system and I plan to use each primary key id as the key for the data.

Is it guaranteed that even after the restoration of a pg_dump, each row will still have the same id?

Comment: Unless you do something very esoteric (such as having an enabled on insert `trigger` that changes it while restoring your data), the answer is YES. PostgreSQL is not working like MS-Access WRT to `autoincrement`, which is called `serial`

Comment: @joanolo AFAIK, triggers don't interfere with pg_restore. They're applied after the dataset.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: if you choose the right (should I say *wrong*?) options, they do. Or, at least, they did. When you restore a *full* database, you normally don't have problems, types, functions, table type definitions, data, constraints, indexes and triggers go in the optimal order. If you restore just the *data* of a table (or schema), and forget to *disable* triggers... things may go wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick overview:

- PostgreSQL does not have `AUTO INCREMENTS`. There is no special type.
- In order to set this up PostgreSQL uses the standard [`IDENTITY COLUMNS`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158988/what-are-identity-columns/169347#169347) which associates a `SEQUENCE` with the `int` type.

Let's create a table,

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  foo_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  bar    int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
);
```

When you `pg_dump` that table with an `IDENTITY COLUMN` you'll see this,

```
CREATE TABLE public.foo (
    foo_id integer NOT NULL,
    bar integer
);
```

That's because the type is simply `int` type. Now, when you load you'll see *right* after the table this,

```
ALTER TABLE public.foo ALTER COLUMN foo_id ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME public.foo_foo_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);
```

This tells the pg_restore the state associated with the sequence the `IDENTITY COLUMN` was using.

```
# \d foo
                             Table "public.foo"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |             Default              
--------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 foo_id | integer |           | not null | generated by default as identity
 bar    | integer |           |          |
```

Then the data is loaded and when it's loaded all of the values of that sequence for each row are specified in the load -- **they maintain the old values from the dump.***

Note that the PostgreSQL implementation of an `IDENTITY COLUMN` which is more less sugar for `SEQUENCE` does not ensure a gaplessness.

## Footnotes

- *I've left off the permission stuff for brevity.*
- *I've removed all of the stuff about `serial`, `bigserial` and what serial was and how it worked because moving forward it should not be a thing. PostgreSQL users should be using `IDENTITY COLUMNS` in all circumstances.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for the detailled answer