# Are PostgreSQL 10.x identity columns inherently indexed? unique?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Are PostgreSQL 10.x identity columns inherently indexed? unique? Or do I need to add a (unique) index to the column as desired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are PostgreSQL 10.x identity columns inherently indexed?

No

> unique?

No

> Or do I need to add a (unique) index to the column as desired?

You don't have to, if you desire it you can. Or just declare the `IDENTITY COLUMN` to be a `PRIMARY KEY` (as they're often used). All `PRIMARY KEY`s are `UNIQUE` and indexed.

See also

- [*What are Identity Columns?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/158988/2639)