# Postgres, how insert "0" value into serial?

Tags: postgresql, insert, sequence

I have a `serial` id in my application table. However, I would like to insert a single `0` id record to mean global.

Is there a way I can insert this into my table without affecting the counter?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious? `INSERT INTO tablename (t_id, ....) VALUES (0, ....) ;`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ no I did not try it, would not have worked in the provider I am accustomed to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, just do it. The counter only gets incremented when you call a [**Sequence Manipulation Function**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html). In the case when you don't explicitly specify a value, the `DEFAULT` triggers a call to `nextval(sequence_name)`

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( id serial );
INSERT INTO foo (id) VALUES (0);
```

## PostgreSQL 10+

It should be noted, that `serial` is the old and antiquated method of doing this. You should be using the standardized [`IDENTITY COLUMNS`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/158988/2639)

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
);
INSERT INTO foo (id) VALUES (0);
```

See also

- [What are Identity Columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/169347/2639)
- [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) (syntax for `IDENTITY COLUMNS`)
- [`CREATE SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) (which has the options for the columns)

Comment: Thanks! I come from a MSSQL background where you have to disable the equivalent to `serial` if you want to insert a specified value. It is a bit involved. This is really easy :)

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer "This is really easy" will be your new moddo. Welcome to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Along with, "How the heck do I make a clustered index?" :P :)

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer it ain't all roses, just 99.9999% of it. =) Objectively.

Comment: Clustered indexes in version 17. In 2024. Until then, everything is a heap ;)